# Backbone model.save() fails unless evaluated in DevTools console first

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this function in a Backbone view:

```
updateToServer: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    var file = this.collection.get(id);
    var data = {};
    $(e.target).serializeArray().map(function(x) {data[x.name] = x.value;});
    file.save(data);
    this.$el.modal('hide');
}
```

If I allow this to run naturally, I get `undefined is not a function` on `file.save(data)`. However, if I set a breakpoint in Chrome DevTools at `file.save(data)` and evaluate that function manually in the console before resuming, both `save` functions work.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here's the entire view in case you need additional context: https://gist.github.com/raddevon/d3ddf1bba101b6b67c4b#file-supportfilesview-js-L155-L163

**Update:** New discovery: On the second run, this works. I have an even listener on form submit. When I click the submit button the first time, I get the error. If I click again, the model saves.

Comment: Wild shot but could it be that: The javascript for the object's prototype returned by "this.collection.get(id)" is still being loaded/evaluated? Your 'breakpoint' would then solve the problem of not having the prototype "save" on the "file" prototype. Just a guess tbh

Comment: @MarvinSmit I suspected that. I hoped, if that were the case, it might be a promise, so I tacked `.done()` onto `this.collection.get()` and put the rest of that code in the callback. I got the same result. What's really curious is that the function always fails, even with the breakpoint, unless I manually evaluate it first.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
updateToServer: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    var file = this.collection.get(id);
    var data = {};
    $(e.target).serializeArray().map(function(x) {data[x.name] = x.value;});        
    this.$el.modal('hide');

    setTimeout(function(){
        file.save(data);
    }, 200); //try with different values for timer

}
```

I have added a 200 millisecond timer.

This might not be your actual solution but at least you will come to know if there is some asynchronous stuff going on before 'file' is actually formed.

Try different values for the timer. I mean keep increasing the timer and see if you are still not able to get rid of the error.

Once you are sure that 'file' is formed asynchronously then you can look into why that's happening.
And try `console.log`s instead of debuggers for debugging so that you can test without pausing the execution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've just tried this going up to a 1 second delay, but I'm still getting the same error. `undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

This was not at all what I suspected, and I hadn't given enough information in the question without realizing it. The line in my code that triggered the exception was `file.save()`, but the actual exception was happening inside Backgrid.

I provide a form to allow users to update models from the collection displayed in a grid. A particular column is defined as an integer column, but I hadn't converted the value coming from the form to an integer. As a result, Backgrid was trying to run `toFixed` on a string. I modified my form serialization code to convert strings containing only integers into integers. Now, everything works as expected.

Here's that serialization code:

```
$(e.target).serializeArray().map(function(x) {
    data[x.name] = x.value === 'on' ? true : x.value;
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(data[x.name])) && isFinite(data[x.name])) {
        data[x.name] = parseInt(data[x.name]);
    }
});
```

If I had to guess, I'd say that's probably a bit naive, but it seems to be working well in my application.

Thanks to everyone for the help!